# How to do oversampling in the case of an unbalanced multilabel dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, dataset

I'm dealing with a multi-label classification problem with a imbalanced dataset. I want to oversample some certain categories with `SMOTE`. However, I don't know how to achieve it since the label is like `[0,1,0,0,1,0,1]`.

Comment: This Kaggle notebook might be of help for oversampling unbalanced dataset with SMOTE. https://www.kaggle.com/qianchao/smote-with-imbalance-data

Comment: I read this, but it's not a multi-label problem.

Comment: Someone is currently working on adding MLSMOTE (multi-label SMOTE) support to the [imbalanced-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) package. See [this pull request](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/pull/707) and [related discussion](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn/issues/340).